# How to use GridSearchCV (python) for maximizing or minimizing a function with parameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, fasttext, gridsearchcv

I would like to maximize a function: `func(minCount, wordNgrams, lr, epoch, loss)`
with GridSearch on only these values:

```
`{'minCount': [2, 3],
'wordNgrams': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'lr': [0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001],
'epoch': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
'loss': [hs, ns, softmax]}`
```

I have read about `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid, ...)`
But, I don't know, **to where I should put** my `func(minCount, wordNgrams, lr, epoch, loss)`

By the way, I've read about bayesian optimization (https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization), but don't have any understanding of how to use this with `string` and `int` parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) , you have two solutions:

- You can pass *estimator = func* to GridSearchCV, but you **also need to pass a scoring function**. The scoring function will take *func*'s outputs and return a score (float) that GridSearchCV will seek to optimize. Example:

```
def my_scoring_function(func_outputs):

  """
  process the outputs of func and return a score. 

  if func already reutrns the value you want to minimize, 
  my_scoring_function will be the identity function.

  score is the value to optimize
  """

  return score


cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=func, param_grid=my_param_grid, scoring=my_scoring_function)
```

- More complex, but elegant: You can rewrite your *func* as an object implementing scikit-learn's estimator methods ([good tutorial here with a gid search example](http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/)). This means that will basically follow a set of conventions that will make your function behave like scikit-learn's objects. GridSearchCV will then know how to deal with it. This might be overkill for your problem though.

Regarding bayesian optimisation, it is interesting if your problem meets the following criterions:

- Evaluating your function is very costly (in terms of time/resource...) and you cannot afford calling it as many times as a grid search requires you to. In your case, you have 720 combinations of parameters to explore, so if one evaluation costs 10s, you will have to run the grid search for 7200s.
- You want to explore a broader parameter space, or you want to search continuous spaces for some parameters. Typically, it can be interesting for the learning rate. In this case, you can also use a random search, [also implemented in scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html).

For more details on bayesian optimization I would recommend [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introductory-example-of-bayesian-optimization-in-python-with-hyperopt-aae40fff4ff0) that I find very comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems, that it works, because there are no exceptions. The new question is how to retrieve best parameters and a maximized function value from this.

Comment: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'    and i don't know, what should be in fit(??)

Comment: Indeed, you need to call the fit() method before beeing able to retrieve the best_estimator_ attribute. The fit method is the one triggering the calculation. If you look at the documentation, the fit() method takes as input X, an "array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)". This is the data you will use to evaluate your function on/train your algorithm. If you have target values (supervised learning), you can pass them as y. If you don't, just pass y=None and GridSearchCV will seek to **maximize** the score (i.e. the output of your scoring function)

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own loss function for GridSearchCV and want to *minimize* the function, you need to pass

```
greater_is_better=False
```

explicitly to **make_scorer** function because GridSearchCV always assumes that it needs to optimize the function to its **maximum**.

Example code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
import numpy as np

# Define your custom loss function (example)
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Implement your custom loss function here
    return np.mean(np.abs(y_true - y_pred))

# Make a scorer that is the negation of your custom loss
custom_loss_scorer = make_scorer(custom_loss, greater_is_better=False)

# Define the parameter grid for GridSearchCV
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100],
    'max_depth': [None, 10, 20]
}

# Create the RandomForestClassifier
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier()

# Create the GridSearchCV object with your custom loss scorer
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    rf_classifier,
    param_grid,
    scoring=custom_loss_scorer,  # Use the negation of your custom loss
    cv=5  # Number of cross-validation folds
)

# Fit the GridSearchCV object to your data
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get the best parameters and best estimator
best_params = grid_search.best_params_
best_estimator = grid_search.best_estimator_
```